# Linking error in Visual Studio - MQTT

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, mqtt

I'm trying to link an external library (Paho MQTT, which is a C library) into my Visual Studio C++ project.
The library files are in a folder called lib, the includes in the folder include.

My "ProjectGrid" (That's how the project is called) Project Folder:

- Debug
- include
- lib
- ProjectGrid
- Release
- ProjectGrid.sln

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017. My project properties are set to:

- VC++ Directories
   ~ Include Directories: $(SolutionDir)\include;
- C/C++
   ~ General
       ~ Additional Include Directories: $(SolutionDir)\include;
- Linker
   ~ General
       ~ Additional Library Directories: $(SolutionDir)\lib;
   ~ Input
       ~ Additional Dependencies: paho-mqtt3c.lib

This properties are set for every configuration (so both, debug and release).

The problem is I'm getting errors like:

- C2238: Unexpected token preceding ";"
- C2146: Syntax error: missing ";" before identifier "MQTTClient_nameValue"

And so on (82 Errors, while the errors are mostly repeating about 10-20 times).

The only file in the project is main.cpp with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MQTTClient.h"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody tell me, whats wrong or what's missing ? I already have a project where I'm using the same library and it's working, but I cant find any differences in the property settings of the linker or so.

Comment: Nobody can tell you what's wrong if you don't show the line that is causing C2238 error.

Comment: At least the lines are from the library itself, they are not in my code. And the library works in another project at least, so there can't be something wrong with the library. But if you want to see the library file, here you are:

C2238: MQTTClient_willOptions* will;
C2146: DLLExport MQTTClient_nameValue* MQTTClient_getVersionInfo(void);
C4430: DLLExport int MQTTClient_setCallbacks(MQTTClient handle, void* context, MQTTClient_connectionLost* cl, MQTTClient_messageArrived* ma, MQTTClient_deliveryComplete* dc);

Just some lines. The library is PAHO MQTT, if you wanna try it on your own.